# Connecting to api using basic auth Angular 8 Express js

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have set up an angular 8 app, that connects to an express API.

I'm running it locally, to test.
My front end app connects to http://localhost:4200/ and backend to http://localhost:3000/
I've set up an express route to connect to https://api.podbean.com/v1/podcasts?access_token=baee9cb65384a814e704adc626dc969bb019f84d
which works fine, returning all podcasts

But the debugToken endpoint never works via the express route, if I use https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/debugToken?access_token=baee9cb65384a814e704adc626dc969bb019f84d
Using postman with basic auth   clientId = '7faf9a7ad38a01c7d900c'  client_secret = 'a7a3825f02be39c57ff44' it works ok, but never when connecting via localhost
I'm using GET

It must be connecting because I get an object returned, although it's an error

In Angular:

```
debug() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('7faf9a7ad38a01c7d900c:a7a3825f02be39c57ff44')
      })
    };
    console.log(httpOptions);
    return this.http.get(`${this.configUrl}/debug/`, httpOptions);
  }
```

Express:

```
  router.get('/debug', function (req, res, next) {
    var options = {
      url: `https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/debugToken?access_token=${accessToken}`
    }
     request(options, function (err, response, body) {
        console.log( req.headers);
       if(err){
         return res.status(500).json({
           title: 'An error has occured',
           error: err
         })
       }
            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
           next();
      })

  });
```

When I log the request headers in the express/node side

```
{host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  authorization: 'Basic N2ZhZjlhN2FkMzhhMDFjN2Q5MDBjOmE3YTM4MjVmMDJiZTM5YzU3ZmY0NA==',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
  dnt: '1',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,es;q=0.6' }
```

Returned object:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":""}
```

Which tells me I'm connecting, just not correctly

Comment: Have you tried switching the token type from 'Basic' to 'Bearer'? This seems to be a configuration issue with the api you are trying to integrate with.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, that doesn't work, the docs say basic auth should be used, also, it works if I use postman and connect directly to the endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just confused endpoints. You are sending basic auth from Angular page to your Express endpoint, 
which doesn't make much sense, because it's https://api.podbean.com who requires authorization, not your Express server.

Try adding basic auth credentials to the request which goes from your Express server to api.podbean.com

```
  router.get('/debug', function (req, res, next) {
    var options = {
      url: `https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/debugToken?access_token=${accessToken}`,
      headers: {               
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer("7faf9a7ad38a01c7d900c:a7a3825f02be39c57ff44").toString('base64')
      }
    }
    request(options, function (err, response, body) {
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had started to add my Authorization to the request from the express by using  var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(clientId+':'+client_secret).toString('base64'); req.headers.authorization = auth; but it wasn't working, but adding to the headers object in options is what did it, thanks again